# Windows Update downloads are very slow

Tags: dns, windows-update, cdn

I'm hoping somebody can suggest a solution as Microsoft help have been unable to provide any ideas.

I'm trying to download updates for Windows 10 from the inbuilt update utility and from the Windows update catalogue.

All downloads from Microsoft sites which go through Akamai are very slow, yet I can get download over HTTP from other sites at around 2mb/s.
From Microsoft sites, downloads average 200kb/s from MSDN, but for updates they frequently drop as low as 7kb/s.

I know people who have seen better download speeds using Google's DNS, but I'm keen not to change my DNS as my ISP provides support for DNS issues.

If anybody can shed some light on any possible alternative causes for the slow download, I would be grateful for any other avenues of investigation I might follow.

Many thanks.

Comment: You should verify the problem does not exist if you chnage your DNs temporarily

Comment: I did try this, but the result was difficult to gauge. Windows update catalogue consistantly fails to give me valid download links, and in the windows update utility, there is no indication of the speed. From observation, it seems to have been a slight improvement, but as the update tool has no speed indicator, it's difficult to confirm.

Comment: There is also a major DDOS attack that's recently happening/happened effecting numerous sites since Akami is in the center of that (one of th few services like it) you could be using a path to your destination that's being attacked

Comment: You provided measurements redo those tests

Comment: Thats a good call - I'm pretty tired at the moment and I'd not considered retrying the download from our MSDN subscription. It's getting late now so I'll give that a try in the morning. I've had poor download speeds for a long time from Akamai, but if theres a DDOS hitting it, it wouldn't help things....

Comment: Use the Resource Monitor in windoes to check the speed.

Comment: I've tried on Google's DNS again, and am seeing a marginal increase in speed - roughly 40kbps rather than 7kbps, so it's an improvement but hardly usable. I'm starting to think that this is just a poor speed for the UK. If that is the case, my options are pretty limited.

Comment: I referred this to the ISP, who made some changes to the routing profile on my account.
This has since resovled the performance issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify the confusion regarding this issue, the resolution was to refer the issue to the ISP who changed the routing  profile on the account.

I do not like to answer my own questions, but as the solution was derrived from suggestions in the comments and this thread has been commented on further, for the sake of completeness I have summarised the comments here as an answer.

Diagnostic steps suggested by Ramhound led me to the solution -

> You should verify the problem does not exist if you chnage your DNs
>   temporarily

This yielded a slight improvement, but nothing major

> I've tried on Google's DNS again, and am seeing a marginal increase in
>   speed - roughly 40kbps rather than 7kbps, so it's an improvement but
>   hardly usable. I'm starting to think that this is just a poor speed
>   for the UK. If that is the case, my options are pretty limited.

After speaking to the ISP, it seems that the DDOS referred to by Ramhound was a contibuting factor.

> There is also a major DDOS attack that's recently happening/happened
>   effecting numerous sites since Akami is in the center of that (one of
>   th few services like it) you could be using a path to your destination
>   that's being attacked

My assumption here is that the routing profile on the account with the ISP was part of the issue, and the DDOS was likely not helping matters.
If routing through to a different location resulted in an unaffected CDN server being selected, it would explain the improvement accounting for both issues.

It's conceivable that the problem was caused by either one of those problems, or a combination fo the two.

Regardless, the issue is now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

i think the best thing to do here is try nslookup of the download domain that you are using. The IP that is returned, check the location of it. If its not somewhere near to from where you are trying then possibly your request is getting served from a server which is quite far from you. One of reason for this is your ISP provider i am afraid. Because Akamai decides the nearest CDN server to you based on the client ISP DNS IP.

Comment: If you'd read the comments you'd see this issue has already been resolved. Please thoroughly read any existing comments and answers before you post your own to make certain the issue is outstanding and that you are not duplicating existing information.

Comment: @music2myear if you were able to fix the problem on your own, you should've posted an answer to your question. People that come here from google won't know the solution is hidden in the comments.

Comment: @andromeda947 Please see this comment: http://superuser.com/questions/1138197/windows-update-downloads-are-very-slow/1183847?noredirect=1#comment1635100_1138197 The issue with Vinod's answer isn't that there isn't an answer other than his, but that his answer is counter to the actual solution at this point, and yet was posted well after the question was asked and solved (if not answered), and so had he read the entire comment thread, he would have seen the solution.